# unfortunately app has stopped working at.davik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeMethod)

Tags: android

i am new to android development so cant fix this piece of code . any help is appreciated 
`

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    ImageView pic,button;
    TextView welcome;
    Facebook fb;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String APP_ID=getString(R.string.APP_ID);
        fb=new Facebook(APP_ID);
        button =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.login);
        pic =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        updateButtonImage();
        Log.d("Main Activity","Activity Created");
        }
        private void updateButtonImage() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(fb.isSessionValid())
        {
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.com_facebook_button_check);
            pic.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

        }
        else
        {
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.com_facebook_button_blue);
        }
      }
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        if(fb.isSessionValid())
        {
            try {
                fb.logout(getApplicationContext());
                updateButtonImage();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("Main Activity","Activity Created");
                }
        else
        {
            fb.authorize(MainActivity.this, new DialogListener() {


                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "FbError",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    updateButtonImage();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onCancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
                }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       fb.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       Log.d("Main Activity","Activity Created");
}
}
```

my xml file is

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context="com.example.jumbo.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@+drawable/com_facebook_button_blue"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/login"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/login"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

logcat file

07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356): Process: com.example.jumbo, PID: 19356
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:224)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.requestImpl(Facebook.java:804)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:707)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.logoutImpl(Facebook.java:649)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.logout(Facebook.java:642)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at com.example.jumbo.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:75)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-01 00:48:36.373: E/AndroidRuntime(19356):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-01 00:48:39.113: I/Process(19356): Sending signal. PID: 19356 SIG: 9

the name of my xml file is activity_main.xml

The app crashes on my device every time i click one of the buttons , I have checked xml files but cant seem to figure out what the problem is .

it shows an error in the logcat at.davik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeMethod)
thank you :)

Comment: post your full logcat output

Comment: what is the name of your xml?

Comment: i just uploaded my logcat file and the name of my xml file is activity_main.xml . Thank you so much guys

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the network on the UI (main) thread. Do not perform these kind of actions on the main thread for they they may cause the application not to be responsive due to latency etc. Try `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html`